# IBM Integration Bus: JSON parser adding special character while writing to MQ

Tags: json, parsing, websphere

I have a flow where I get JOSN data from a HTTP Input node. I store the JSON data in Environment variable.
Code:
`CREATE LASTCHILD OF Environment DOMAIN ('JSON') FROM InputRoot.JSON;`

Later in the code I create a output from the environment variable and put to a file as well to a MQ Queue.
Code:
`SET OutputRoot.JSON = Environment.JSON;`

The JSON data has a date field as String.
Code:
"startDate": "06/01/2020"

The file gets created with proper JSON data but the MQ message has extra special character for the date field.
Code:
`startDate="06\/01\/2020"`

I am not getting the reason why the MQ message get special characters around the "/".

Any suggestion.

Comment: Not sure you are actually attaching the JSON parser to your output. Maybe try what you did on the input side. CREATE LASTCHILD OF OutputRoot DOMAIN ('JSON') FROM Environment.JSON;

Comment: If you want to see what's happening put a Trace node into your flow  at the output shows which parser has been attached or if you are using ACE the mqsichangetrace with the -l debugTree option